# Consider the set $E = \{0,1,2\}$, compute $\operatorname{card}(E\cup P(E))$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set $N$ of natural numbers is defined axiomatically either by $0 = \emptyset, 1 = \{0\}, 2 = \{0,1\}, 3 = \{0,1,2\}, \ldots$ or by Peano axioms.
Consider the set $E = \{0,1,2\}$, compute $\operatorname{card}(E \cup P(E))$, where $P(E)$ is the power set of $E$.

The natural and realistic answer seems to be 11. When we use: 0 = Ø, 1 = {0}, 2 = {0,1}, 3 = {0,1,2}, ... , we obtain as answer 8, but when we use Peano axioms we can get as response 8, 9, 10, or 11 depending on the choice of the set that represents N, is this normal?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It will help users respond to your post more effectively if you provide more information about what's confusing you with this problem and the attempts you've made to solve it. For example, do you understand the meaning of $\text{card}$ and $P(E)$ here? What is $P(E)$ for this particular set? If you don't know the answer to that, why don't you? What's confusing you?

Comment: Thank you, I think that the answer by Andrej Bauer has clarified the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "define" the natural numbers by Peano axioms in the sense that they determine a specific set. The Peano axioms *describe* what properties the set of natural numbers is supposed to have. There may be many sets which satisfy these axioms, and indeed there are.

The most common one is the set $\omega$ of finite von Neuman ordinals which you indicated in your question, i.e., $0 = \emptyset, 1 = \{0\}, 2 = \{0, 1\}, \ldots, n+1 = \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}, \ldots$, together with the relevant operations $S$, $+$ and $\times$. Another would be $0 = \emptyset$, $1 = \{0\}$, $2 = \{1\}, \ldots, n+1 = \{n\}, \ldots$ with suitably defined operations. In fact any countably infinite set may be endowed with operations that satisfy Peano axioms. This is all well-known and not surprising at all. All the different structures satisfying Peano axioms are in fact isomorphic, so in a sense they are "all alike". (Note: I am considering here a "second-order" version of induction that refers to all subsets, rather than an axiom schema, so that I do not get into questions about ultrapowers an non-standard models, as these are completely irelevant to the issue that is bothering Driss).

What you have noticed is that isomorphic structures can have different set-theoretic properties: depending on which isomorphic version of natural numbers we take, the cardinality of $\{0,1,2\} \cup P(\{0,1,2\})$ may indeed be this or that number. Admittedly, this is a bit unsatisfactory because it leads to the so-called "garbage theorems" that hold purely as a coincidence of a particular concrete choice of a mathematical structure. There are alternative approaches to set theory, such as [structural set theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory) and type theory, that try to alleviate these probems.

Some people would instead say that everything is fine with set theory, but you shouldn't make non-sensical statements or wonder about sets that are irrelevant to the structure at hand. That is, if you are studying a certain kind of mathematical structures, then all your statements and objects should be invariant under isomorphisms for that kind of structures. For instance, a good topological notion is such that if a topological space $X$ has it and $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$, then $Y$ also has it. If you consider notions or objects which do not respect isomorphism, it is your own fault that you get garbage. The cardinality of $\{0,1,2\} \cup P(\{0,1,2\})$ is then just "set-theoretic garbage". In contrast, the *disjoint* union $\{0,1,2\} + P(\{0,1,2\})$ is not garbage because it respects isomorphism: if we replace the natural numbers with an isomorphic version, we get an isomorphic set.

However, in my opinion one cannot always do everything in an isomorphism-invariant way. Sooner or later one is forced to get down to concrete details and refer to a particular concrete choice of sets. In that moment isomorphism invariance is potentially lost.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very satisfactory.